# How to make continuous a discontinuous sequence of character numbers with leading zero(s)?

Tags: r, string

I have this character vector:

```
dput(t$line)
c("0304", "0305", "0306", "0308", "0311", "0313", "0314", "0316", 
"0318", "0321", "0322", "0323", "0324", "0326", "0327", "0330", 
"0333", "0337", "0338", "0339", "0342", "0341", "0344", "0346", 
"0347", "0348", "0349", "0350", "0352", "0353", "0357", "0359", 
"0360", "0362", "0363", "0364", "0365", "0367", "0371", "0370", 
"0373", "0375", "0378", "0380", "0381", "0385", "0386", "0387", 
"0391", "0395", "0394", "0397", "0398", "0399", "0400", "0402", 
"0404", "0405", "0406", "0408", "0412", "0416", "0419", "0423", 
"0424", "0425", "0426", "0428", "0429", "0432", "0433", "0436", 
"0435", "0439", "0437", "0440", "0441")
```

The numbers it contains are not completely continuous. I'd like to make them continuous, while preserving the leading zero or zeros where needed. I've come up with this solution:

```
paste("0", seq(as.numeric(t$line[1]), as.numeric(t$line[1]) + length(t$line), 1), sep = "")
 [1] "0304" "0305" "0306" "0307" "0308" "0309" "0310" "0311" "0312" "0313" "0314" "0315" "0316" "0317" "0318" "0319" "0320"
[18] "0321" "0322" "0323" "0324" "0325" "0326" "0327" "0328" "0329" "0330" "0331" "0332" "0333" "0334" "0335" "0336" "0337"
[35] "0338" "0339" "0340" "0341" "0342" "0343" "0344" "0345" "0346" "0347" "0348" "0349" "0350" "0351" "0352" "0353" "0354"
[52] "0355" "0356" "0357" "0358" "0359" "0360" "0361" "0362" "0363" "0364" "0365" "0366" "0367" "0368" "0369" "0370" "0371"
[69] "0372" "0373" "0374" "0375" "0376" "0377" "0378" "0379" "0380" "0381"
```

This works okay as long as there is exactly *one* `0` to be added. There may however be more than one leading zero or none at all. How can the sequence be made continuous with appropriate leading zeros?

Comment: So you don't know before hand if you have 1 zero or 2 zero at the start? That need to be found from data? If you have another number '00443' at the end. What would be the output? Rest of the values would have only 1 zero and last number would have 2 zeroes?

Comment: The numbers can only be four digits long. They start from 1, that is, they may have three, two, one, or no `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `stringr` option could be:

```
str_pad(seq.int(min(as.numeric(x)), length.out = length(x)), 4, "left", "0")

 [1] "0304" "0305" "0306" "0307" "0308" "0309" "0310" "0311" "0312" "0313" "0314" "0315" "0316"
[14] "0317" "0318" "0319" "0320" "0321" "0322" "0323" "0324" "0325" "0326" "0327" "0328" "0329"
[27] "0330" "0331" "0332" "0333" "0334" "0335" "0336" "0337" "0338" "0339" "0340" "0341" "0342"
[40] "0343" "0344" "0345" "0346" "0347" "0348" "0349" "0350" "0351" "0352" "0353" "0354" "0355"
[53] "0356" "0357" "0358" "0359" "0360" "0361" "0362" "0363" "0364" "0365" "0366" "0367" "0368"
[66] "0369" "0370" "0371" "0372" "0373" "0374" "0375" "0376" "0377" "0378" "0379" "0380"
```

Comment: Looks nice. But the last value `"0381"` is missing. How can it be included?

Comment: Given the length of the original vector, it should end like this. The length should be 77.

Comment: I guess you're right. I just can't quite understand though why my solution yields 78 results, whereas yours has 77. Any idea?

Comment: Because you created a sequence from the first element to the first element + the length of the vector. Thus, 304 + 77 == 381.

Answer (score 2):

You want a continuous sequence of `length(x)` starting at `min(x)`, where `nchar` of the resulting elements is identical to that of `x`.

Use `sprintf` instead of `paste0` to format leading zeros. `nchar(x)[1]` gives the length to which (occasional) padding with zeros is required. If it's not safe that the lengths are equal use `max(nchar(x))`, but that's slower.

Since `x[1]` does not necessarily have to be the minimum you may want to use `min(as.numeric(x))` as starting point. When you use `seq`, it's end point should be `min(as.numeric(x)) + length(x) - 1` (because the min is already the first element). Or use `length.out=length(x)` which appears to be faster, combined with `seq.int` even faster.

```
sprintf(paste0("%0", nchar(x)[1], "d"), seq.int(min(as.numeric(x)), length.out=length(x)))
# [1] "0304" "0305" "0306" "0307" "0308" "0309" "0310" "0311" "0312" "0313" "0314" "0315"
# [13] "0316" "0317" "0318" "0319" "0320" "0321" "0322" "0323" "0324" "0325" "0326" "0327"
# [25] "0328" "0329" "0330" "0331" "0332" "0333" "0334" "0335" "0336" "0337" "0338" "0339"
# [37] "0340" "0341" "0342" "0343" "0344" "0345" "0346" "0347" "0348" "0349" "0350" "0351"
# [49] "0352" "0353" "0354" "0355" "0356" "0357" "0358" "0359" "0360" "0361" "0362" "0363"
# [61] "0364" "0365" "0366" "0367" "0368" "0369" "0370" "0371" "0372" "0373" "0374" "0375"
# [73] "0376" "0377" "0378" "0379" "0380"
```

Another option is using colon `:`, but `seq.int` above appears to be faster (see benchmark below).

```
sprintf(paste0("%0", nchar(x)[1], "d"), 0:(length(x) - 1) + min(as.numeric(x)))
```

NB: To complete the original vector by imputing missings, you may do:

```
sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(x)), "d"), do.call(`:`, as.list(range(as.numeric(x)))))
# [1] "0304" "0305" "0306" "0307" "0308" "0309" "0310" "0311" "0312" "0313" "0314"
# [12] "0315" "0316" "0317" "0318" "0319" "0320" "0321" "0322" "0323" "0324" "0325"
# [23] "0326" "0327" "0328" "0329" "0330" "0331" "0332" "0333" "0334" "0335" "0336"
# [34] "0337" "0338" "0339" "0340" "0341" "0342" "0343" "0344" "0345" "0346" "0347"
# [45] "0348" "0349" "0350" "0351" "0352" "0353" "0354" "0355" "0356" "0357" "0358"
# [56] "0359" "0360" "0361" "0362" "0363" "0364" "0365" "0366" "0367" "0368" "0369"
# [67] "0370" "0371" "0372" "0373" "0374" "0375" "0376" "0377" "0378" "0379" "0380"
# [78] "0381" "0382" "0383" "0384" "0385" "0386" "0387" "0388" "0389" "0390" "0391"
# [89] "0392" "0393" "0394" "0395" "0396" "0397" "0398" "0399" "0400" "0401" "0402"
# [100] "0403" "0404" "0405" "0406" "0407" "0408" "0409" "0410" "0411" "0412" "0413"
# [111] "0414" "0415" "0416" "0417" "0418" "0419" "0420" "0421" "0422" "0423" "0424"
# [122] "0425" "0426" "0427" "0428" "0429" "0430" "0431" "0432" "0433" "0434" "0435"
# [133] "0436" "0437" "0438" "0439" "0440" "0441"
```

### Benchmark

```
f1 <- function() sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(x)), "d"),
                         seq(min(as.numeric(x)), min(as.numeric(x)) + length(x) - 1))
f2 <- function() sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(x)), "d"),
                         seq(min(as.numeric(x)), length.out=length(x)))
f3 <- function() sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(x)), "d"),
                         seq.int(min(as.numeric(x)), length.out=length(x)))
f31 <- function() sprintf(paste0("%0", nchar(x[1]), "d"),
                         seq.int(min(as.numeric(x)), length.out=length(x)))
f4 <- function() sprintf(paste0("%0", nchar(x[1]), "d"),
                         0:(length(x) - 1) + min(as.numeric(x)))
f5 <- function() stringr::str_pad(seq.int(min(as.numeric(x)),
                                          length.out=length(x)),
                                  nchar(x[1]), "left", "0")

set.seed(5789)
x <- sample(sprintf("%05d", 1:99999))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(seq_to=f1(), seq_len=f2(), seq.int=f3(),
                               seq.int1=f31(), colon=f4(), stringr=f5())
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval    cld
#   seq_to 104.22119 106.83928 108.92791 107.81301 109.68406 124.35686   100      f
#  seq_len  87.14385  89.89180  92.34962  90.97192  92.09823 110.59426   100    d  
#  seq.int  85.72324  87.93885  89.91353  89.03327  90.32758 113.41480   100   c   
# seq.int1  59.54312  61.63065  62.86618  62.47707  63.53334  76.33471   100 a     
#    colon  60.94867  63.16109  64.73306  63.88925  64.79997  81.63646   100  b    
#  stringr  99.08452 101.56649 104.01522 102.74420 104.20269 158.30948   100     e
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it should have the length of the original vector.

Comment: @tmfmnk You are right, that was probably too much of a good thing!

Comment: I mean his example does insert missing values, so I think your original solution was the more correct one? Nevertheless it would probably need more info to solve completly

Comment: @Julian_Hn Well, now the answer provides both options!

Comment: Re 1st solution: the sequence is still discontinuous; e.g., `# [1] "0304" "0305" "0306" "0308"`. Re 2nd solution: I do not want to impute missings but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Chris Ruhlemann:But you can't have both? Either you need to impute or you have missing values. How should you be able to have both things together?

Comment: @Julian_Hn With _"make them continuous"_ , OP probably meant a sequence of length `length(x)` starting at `min(x)`.

Comment: @jay.sf Ah. Yeah that seems to be it. Strange wording then imo, but glad someone else understood it correctly

Comment: The edit is a nice job. Thanks. I can't quite understand though why my solution yields 78 results, whereas yours has 77. Any idea? (I guess 77 is right and 78 is wrong, just why?)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Because you attempt to count you first element twice (your original vector also is of length 77, isn't it?), see explanation in last edit. I also did a benchmark, which became quite interesting!

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution that takes into account the maximum length of the entries and therefore implictly the number of leading zeros:

```
t$line2 <- c("000517","00524")

Cont.PadZero <- function(vec) sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(vec)), "d"), seq.int(min(as.numeric(vec)), max(as.numeric(vec))))

Cont.PadZero(t$line2)
[1] "000517" "000518" "000519" "000520" "000521" "000522" "000523" "000524"
```

Comment: I do not want to impute missings.